# How to get values for one case across multiple rows into one row using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, select, group-by, pivot

I have data on individual students’ grades in their first semester of school in multiple rows. Imagine one row for math, another for English, another for science.

```
Student A – Math – 70
Student A – Science – 84
Student A – English – 90
```

How would I get the output like:

```
Student Math Grade Science Grade English Grade
A         70            84            90
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    student,
    max(case when topic = 'Math' then grade end) math,
    max(case when topic = 'Science' then grade end) science,
    max(case when topic = 'English' then grade end) english
from mytable
group by student
order by student
```